# Linux no module named azure.iot.hub

Tags: python, pip, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm having an issue trying to execute a very simple python script that works perfectly in Windows but not on my Le Potato (Debian):

```py
import uuid
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
import MqttClient as mqttClient


CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=(...)"
DEVICE_ID = "(...)"
registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)

def send_message(msg):
    props = {}
    props.update(messageId = str(uuid.uuid4()))
    props.update(contentType = "application/json")
    props.update()
    registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, msg, properties=props)


def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    print("[" + msg.topic+"]: "+str(msg.payload))
    try:
        send_message(str(msg.payload))
    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred:", str(e))

mqttClient.init(on_message=on_message)
```

When running `python myscript.py` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.iot.hub'`

I installed everything several times:

- `pip install azure-iot-hub`
- `pip install azure-iot-device`

And I even created my own virtual environment with a fresh install and tried the same exact versions in Windows.

### Update: other tests

I have tried some more things:

1. `pip show azure-iot-hub` prints the following:

```
Name: azure-iot-hub
(...)
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages
Requires: azure-core, msrest, uamqp
Required-by:
```

It seems it installs the packages on `/usr/local` and my python installation seems to be somewhere else:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/offiman/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages']
```

So I tried to move every package from `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/` to `/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/`. Still nothing.

2. Folder `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/azure/iot` is completely empty, seems weird.

Comment: could you please what you trying to do with above code

Comment: are implement in Visual Studio code

Comment: I am trying to send c2d messages (send_c2d_message), I am going to edit the question and add the complete source code as it is very small. In Windows it is implemented using Visual Studio Code. I just copied the source code into Linux

Comment: uninstall/install VS code, python `3.10.9`

Comment: run `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: and install again `pip install azure-iot-hub`

Comment: Unfortunately `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` did not change anything. My current pip version is `23.2.1`. Also Python version `3.10.9` in Linux seems not available. I executed `sudo apt install python 3.10.9` and it threw `Unable to locate package 3.10.9`

Comment: uninstall/install VS code run as  `administrator` make sure reload the extension

Comment: Refer to this git [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/627) and `install padas`

Comment: `pip3 install azure-iot-device azure-iot-hub`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot find `padas`, I only found https://pypi.org/project/pada/ , maybe you misspelled something? I have also tried to install both packages at the same time. with your command

Comment: `pip install pandas` or  `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: That did not change anything, sorry.

Comment: Does  `pip list`  work and also `pip --version` also reboot the system once install `pip3 install azure-iot-device azure-iot-hub` and check again `pip list`

Comment: `pip list` returns `azure-core          1.29.3`, `azure-iot-device    2.12.0` and also `azure-iot-hub       2.6.1`. Rebooting did nothing either, it seems a problem with Le Potato (Raspberry Pi)

Comment: Then `azure-core`  `azure-iot-device` and also `azure-iot-hub`   are installed .I will give a sample code with your code. So you test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issues with you on RPi4 running fresh installed Bullseye.
Was not able to import azure.iot.hub modules both from python script and cmdline interrupter. While all other azure modules i.e. azure.core / azure.iot.device work find and was installed the same way as azure.iot.hub in same dir.

I tried installing the module via all different method, with/wihtout sudo, pip, pip3, python -m pip , python3 -m pip... all to make sure the its installed properly.

In my case, i end up finding the module was not actually installed in the path. And have to manually copy the source file over to fix the issues.(`/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/azure/iot/hub` is missing)

1. Install module via pip `python3 -m pip install azure_iot_hub`
2. Check the installation path for the module `pip3 list -v`, in my case, i have the module located at `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/`
3. Download the Built Distributions from pypl : https://pypi.org/project/azure-iot-hub/#files
4. Copy the source file form `../azure/iot/hub` in the zip file, to the installation path, i.e.`/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/azure/iot/hub`
5. That should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using this reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/c2d-messaging-python#send-a-cloud-to-device-message)  able to Send cloud-to-device messages.

- Git issues [Question](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/627).

[image]

- Install  `pip install azure-iot-hub` , `pip3 install azure-iot-hub` and`pip3 install  uuid`
- With  `pip list` we can check the respective module is installed .

[image]

[image]

- Replace with your IoT Hub connection [string](https://i.imgur.com/lplHuY2.png) and [device ID](https://i.imgur.com/zR3H2iN.png)

**Code:**

```py
import  random
import  uuid
from  azure.iot.hub  import  IoTHubRegistryManager
CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=sampath23sa454.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iot"
DEVICE_ID = "sampath23"
registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
def  send_message(msg):
props = {
"messageId":  str(uuid.uuid4()),
"contentType":  "application/json"
}
registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID,  msg,  properties=props)
print("Message sent successfully!")
print("Message content:",  msg)
def  on_message(mqttc,  obj,  msg):
print("[" + msg.topic + "]: " + str(msg.payload))
try:
send_message(str(msg.payload))
except  Exception  as  e:
print("An exception occurred:",  str(e))
class  MqttClient:
@staticmethod
def  init(on_message):
pass
mqttClient = MqttClient()
mqttClient.init(on_message=on_message)
if  __name__ == '__main__':
print("Starting the IoT Hub C2D Messaging sample...")
message_to_send = "Hello from the cloud!"
send_message(message_to_send)
input("Press Enter to stop...\n")
print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging sample stopped")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```py
mqttClient = MqttClient()
mqttClient.init(on_message=on_message)
if  __name__ == '__main__':
print("Starting the IoT Hub C2D Messaging sample...")
random_messages = ["Temperature: 25°C",  "Humidity: 50%",  "Pressure: 1013 hPa"]
for  _  in  range(5):  # Sending 5 random messages
random_message = random.choice(random_messages)
send_message(random_message)
input("Press Enter to stop...\n")
print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging sample stopped")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried but still same issue. Something interesting is that when I open the terminal and execute `python` (Python REPL) and I add `from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager` still the same issue is thrown there

Answer (score 0):

linux see root and non-root as different users, are you running your python code at the same user you installed these dependencies?
for example if you run it by sudo, you need to reinstall those libraries on root too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you clarify "if you run it by sudo, you need to reinstall those libraries on root too"?

I have tried to reinstall the dependencies by running `sudo pip3 install azure-iot-device azure-iot-hub` and executed the Python script with `sudo myscript.py`. However it still throws the same error. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I can see in my logs while installing with pip `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`. Maybe it is related

Comment: What i mean is pip installs dependencies for any user seperatly, in other words you can not use library you installed on user A account in user B account and you have to install it again or globally. Root is also considered as a diffrent user from your current one. So when you use sudo you install dependencies on root and cant use it with normal user

Comment: I see. I have also tried to uninstall everything, log in as root (I know it's not recommended but I'm out of ideas) tried to install everything again with `pip` and still nothing :(

Comment: this is weird, it seems you're doing everything right.
can you try it on another OS so we can see if there is a problem with azure.iot.hub itself or installation ?

Comment: In Windows it works perfectly fine, it must be an issue with the Python installation of Le Potato.

Comment: then you may want to containerize it with docker or something to make it work independent of your current OS.